# Why are we allowed to replace the integral with respect to the product measure $\mu$ with iterated integrals?(2)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

My statement for Fubini theorem is:

{Let $(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{T}, \lambda)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. and let $f$ be a $\mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{T}-$measurable function on $X \times Y.$ if $f$ is a real-valued and if $\psi^*(x) = \int_{Y}|f_{x}|d\lambda$ and if $\int_{X} \phi^* d\mu < \infty$ then $f\in L^1(\mu \times \lambda).$

**My question is:**

In the answer for this question  [Why are we allowed to replace the integral with respect to the product measure $\mu$ with iterated integrals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559137/why-are-we-allowed-to-replace-the-integral-with-respect-to-the-product-measure) I do not understand why $f$ is  $\mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{T}-$measurable function on $X \times Y.$ so, could someone please show me how to fulfill the assumptions of Fubini as I am confused a little bit ?

My $\phi(x) = \lambda (\phi_{x})= \int_{Y} \chi_{\phi_{x}}(yd\lambda(y)),$ therefore, $\int_{X} \phi^* d\mu = \int_{X}d\mu(x)\int_{Y}|f|d\lambda (y).$ I am not sure if my $\int_{X} \phi^* d\mu$ is correct or if it should be the $x-$ section of $f$? Could anyone check this for me please?

Comment: " I do not understand why f is S×T−measurable function on X×Y" <- This is an assumption made in the statement of the theorem.

Comment: @StefanHansen yes , so to apply the theorem I have to be sure that my function is measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this. The integrand is measurable because it is continuous (redefining $\sin x/x$ at $0$ in the usual way.)

We have

$\psi^*(x) = \int_{E_Y}|f_{x}|dy=\int_0^{\sqrt x}\left|\frac{y}{x} e^{-x}\sin x\right|dy\le 2\int_0^{\sqrt x}y\ dy$

and

$\phi^*(y) = \int_{E_X}|f_{y}|dx=\int_{y^2}^{\infty}\left|\frac{y}{x} e^{-x}\sin x\right|dx\le 2y\int_{y^2}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ dx$

and each of these is finite.

On the other hand, your statement of Fubini is not clear as it stands. If you use the [standard statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) instead, then the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559137/why-are-we-allowed-to-replace-the-integral-with-respect-to-the-product-measure/3559176#3559176) to your question is a bit easier.

Comment: I need your help in this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3570599/a-different-statement-for-fubinis-theorem-and-correcting-a-solution#3570649  it is related to other questions you answered me on Fubini's theorem